# How to set env properties in vue js dynamically at deployment time as a springboot application

Tags: spring-boot, maven, vue.js

I have packaged Vue Js and Springboot (Frontend & Backend) in a Jar file and vue file are getting packaged as static content in side the jar file.
I also have UI (Frontend) specific env variable properties in JS files which gets configured into jar at the time of build (npm run build) but I want my jar to be generic and set theses Env properties at runtime/deployment.

```js
'use strict'
const merge = require('webpack-merge')
const prodEnv = require('./prod.env')

module.exports = merge(prodEnv, {
  NODE_ENV: '"dev"',
  PUT_DESIGNER_DOMAIN: '"mydesign-dev..com"'
  APP_DOMAIN: '"app-dev.int.com"'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create different .env files with different names such as .env.dev, .env.prod.

And Create custom npm build commands using --mode for different environments. You can create different dist files for different environments.

Here is documentation;

https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables

Comment: I have Done this first part (Create custom npm build commands using --mode for different environments) but not sure how to generate different dist for different environment, Could you please guide or provide some doc for this.

Comment: Actually I think it is better to separate those two and serve static files outside (on an Apache Server maybe). You should not need to build a backend just to change a button name on front end. For your case; If remember it right there are maven plugins for this kind of situation.